# Bibtex reference style cannot be changed

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to add citations to a paper I've written, I've created them using citethisforme.com which allows you to export a .bib file.

I'm using a Springer LLNCS template, which came with a 'llncs.cls' and a 'splncs04.bst' file.

I have a .bib file called 'neutrino.bib' and at the end of my document I have

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\bibliography{neutrino}
```

The bibliography doesn't look the way I want, so I've tried replacing 'splncs04' with 'plain' and I've removed the .bst file, but the reference layout stays exactly the same, no matter what argument I enter.

How can I fix this?

[Edit]: I've noticed that changing styles DOES change the lay-out, but not quite the way it's supposed to:
[image: splncs04]
[image: plain]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Did you run BibTeX after you changed `splncs04` to `plain` (or to any other style)?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Overleaf so I assume that happens automatically

Comment: Did you test this assumption?

Comment: @Joshua I was reading [this page](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/532-creating-and-managing-bibliographies-with-bibtex-on-overleaf) and discovered that Overleaf uses `latexmk` to do the automatic stuff (the paragraph just above *A note on compilation times*). I don't use `latexmk`, so everything from this point may be pure gargabe: As far as I know `latexmk` uses `synctex` (which I don't use either), so the source file has to change for the program to *actually* run. Try adding a different citation to the document to force a refresh of BibTeX. Again, this may be garbage :/

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but adding a citation doesn't seem to help. @Mico I did after submitting, I've just noticed that changing the style DOES change the lay-out, but not the way it's supposed to. I've included images in the original post.

Comment: I came up with a very ad-hoc solution... I copied the contents of my latex file to another document, changed that document's class to paper, compiled this and took out the last page with references as a single PDF and then embedded the PDF in my original file. I was really sick of it not working.